# Mutable state of empty List

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I would like do a mutableStateOf for my umpty list because I don't have items to put in yet.

```
@Composable
fun AppScaffold(){
    val navigationController = rememberNavController()
    var type by remember { mutableStateOf()}
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { AppBarTop() },
        containerColor = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface
    ){paddingValues ->
        NavHost(
            navController = navigationController,
            startDestination = Screens.POKEDEX.name,
            modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues)
        ){
            composable(route = Screens.POKEDEX.name){
                AppContent(onClick = {
                    type = it
                    navigationController.navigate(route = Screens.DETAILS.name)
                })
            }
            composable(route = Screens.DETAILS.name){
                DetailView(type = type)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my main Function.
I receive a Types from my AppContent View.

My data class is :

```
data class PokedexResults(
    val list: List<Types>
)

data class Types(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val image: String,
    val stats: PokemonStats,
    val apiTypes: List<apiTypes>
)

data class PokemonStats(
    val HP: Int,
    val attack: Int,
    val defense: Int,
    val special_attack: Int,
    val special_defense: Int,
)

data class apiTypes(
    val name: String,
    val image: String
)
```

I tried this
`var type by remember { mutableStateOf(PokedexResults().list)}`
[image: error]

I tried to have a mutable state of because i need to change the type when another is received from my AppContent View

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an empty List in Kotlin, you can use the [`emptyList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/empty-list.html#emptylist) or [`listOf()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) function:

```
var myList by remember { mutableStateOf(emptyList())}  // create empty List
```

In your case, you could use

```
var type by remember { mutableStateOf(PokedexResults(emptyList()).list)}
```

You can also consider to provide a default value for the list parameter of the `PokedexResults` data class like this:

```
data class PokedexResults(
    val list: List<Types> = emptyList()
)
```

Then, when no list is provided, it will automatically initialize the list to an empty list.

Edit: 
 Make sure to adapt your code to properly handle cases where the List is empty. Using the [`first()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first.html#first) function on an empty List will throw an `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: I want to have my type variable to be a mutable state of Types?

Comment: When I have the parameter listOf() in my PokedexResult the app return this error : FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.example.pokedex, PID: 11972
                                                                                                    java.util.NoSuchElementException: List is empty.
                                                                                                     at kotlin.collections.CollectionsKt___CollectionsKt.first(_Collections.kt:214) ...

Comment: I prefer `emptyList()` because it’s very clear it’s intentionally empty and is a little less cognitive load to interpret.

Comment: @lerey, don’t call `first()` on a list that might be empty. You can guard your call with `if (list.isNotEmpty())` or use `firstOrNull()`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Thanks for the hint towards `emptyList`, I did not know this function existed. Learned something new today!